# Sort array based on unknown field values

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting

I have an array which looks like this:

```
  [ { average_cpu: 0.5,
    node_url: 'http://111.11.1111/nodes',
    __v: 0 },
  { average_cpu: 0,
    node_url: 'http://111.11.1111/nodes',
    __v: 0 },
  { average_cpu: 0,
    node_url: 'http://111.11.1111/nodes',
    __v: 0 },
  { average_cpu: 20,
    node_url: 'http://22.22.22/nodes',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

So there are 4 different object, with 3 different values. What I want to achieve, is split/group this array based on the `node_url` - so the ideal final effect is that I will have two different arrays, which look like this:

```
    var array1 = [ { average_cpu: 0.5,
    node_url: 'http://111.11.1111/nodes',
    __v: 0 },
  { average_cpu: 0,
    node_url: 'http://111.11.1111/nodes',
    __v: 0 },
  { average_cpu: 0,
    node_url: 'http://111.11.1111/nodes',
    __v: 0 } ]

    var array2 = [ { average_cpu: 20,
    node_url: 'http://22.22.22/nodes',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

However, I do not know the node_url in advance, therefore I am not 100% sure how to do this. I have tried using `_.groupBy`, however I am unable to get the results back as I do not know the exact values of the `node_url`

Is there another way to achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using _.groupBy you just can do something like this:

```js
var source= [ { average_cpu: 0.5,
    node_url: 'http://111.11.1111/nodes',
    __v: 0 },
  { average_cpu: 0,
    node_url: 'http://111.11.1111/nodes',
    __v: 0 },
  { average_cpu: 0,
    node_url: 'http://111.11.1111/nodes',
    __v: 0 },
  { average_cpu: 20,
    node_url: 'http://22.22.22/nodes',
    __v: 0 } ]

var grouped=_.groupBy(source, function (e) {
  return e.node_url;
  });

//for (let group in grouped) {
//  console.log('*********Elements in group ' + group+': *******')
//  console.log(grouped[group]);
//}

//For nodejs
Object.keys(grouped).forEach(function(key) {
  var group = grouped[key];
  console.log('*********Elements in group ' + key+': *******')
  console.log(group);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this using node js? As node js doe not let me use the following - for (let group in grouped)

Comment: Updated for [nodejs] compatibility

Comment: You sir are a genius! Thankyou. Slightly off-topic, but is there a way for me too loop through each of these 'groups' so that I can get an array of the average_cpu for each node_url? E.g. Node_url "http://111.11.1111/nodes" will have an array of 0.5,0,0 and node_url "http://22.22.22/nodes" will have just 20?